# Identify and count matching dataframes in R?

Tags: r

Lets say I have a list of dataframes, e.g

```
    list.df <- replicate(1000, 
data.frame(l = sample(letters[1:5], 4), n = sample(c(1:4), 4)), 
simplify = F)
```

How can I count the number of times the same dataframe occurs in the list?

Comment: Multiple dataframes can occur multiple times. For eg - Dataframe `A` can occur 2 times, Dataframe `B` can occur 3 times. What would be your expected output?

Comment: A further nested dataframe perhaps, where one column is each of the unique dataframes from the first list, and then an n/counts column?

Answer (score 0):

First you should id the unique data.frames:

```
unique.df <- unique(list.df)
```

Then compute occurence of each of them looping on the `list.df` and counting how many time they occure:

```
n_occurence <- NULL
for (elt in unique.df){
  n_occ <- 0 # A counter of occurence for this e
  for (df in list.df){
    if (identical(elt, df)){ # If df is exactly elt, we count it
      n_occ <- n_occ + 1
    }
  }
  n_occurence <- c(n_occurence, n_occ)
}
```

`n_occurence`is a list of the number of occurence of each element of `unique.df`.

And to control:

```
> sum(n_occurence) == 1000
[1] TRUE
```

Now it is up to you to give it the shape you would want...

---

Just out of curioisty... why do you want to do that? What is your use case?